# Getting an error while finding minimum in list

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

I am trying to find minimum value in list of tuples only from "first" values, is there any better way?

My code:

```
list = [[47  2][47  3][47  4][47  5][48  1][48  2][48  3][49  1][49  2]]
_min = 1000
for tuple_value in list:
   first, second = tuple_value 
   if first < _min:
      _min = first

print(_min) # 47
```

When I am trying something like this:

```
print(min(list[0][0]))
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I'm surprised this even reaches runtime, your list should be caught as a SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of tuples (which you don't have in your post, but you say so in the title), you can do this:

```
l = [(2, 3), (5, 6), (12, 13)]
min(l, key = lambda t: t[0])
```

This will loop over the tuples and find the min for the first element in all tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using numpy the array shape is, *nx2* you can find min just by indexing the array to the first column, if its not a ndarray, you can recast it to one using `reshape`

```
np.min(list[:,0])

np.min(list.reshape(-1,2)[:,0])
```

I would also avoid using keywords as var names.

Answer (score -1):

You have no commas! Spaces mean nothing in python. You must separate values with commas in a list. Very very very basic python.

Edit: Also this problem can easily be solved doing something like `min(tup[0] for tup in my_list)`